# Как задать директорию для данных postgresql за пределами docker контейнера

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Есть файл `docker-compose.yaml` запускающий группу контейнеров и контейнер с Postgres в том числе.

Как я понял, задавая параметр `volumes`, я могу задать ассоциацию между директорией за пределами контейнера, и данными самого Postgres внутри контейнера:

```
volumes:
  - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Но при попытке пройти по пути `/var/lib/postgresql/data` на машине хоста я не нахожу никаких данных.

`docker-compose.yaml` целиком:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1
      POSTGRES_DB: statistic
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  api:
    build: api/
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8083:8080
  ui:
    build: ui/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8082:80

volumes:
  dbdata: {}
```

1. Почему в `/var/lib/postgresql/data` нет данных, что я не так понял, что на самом деле означает запись `dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data`?
2. Что на самом деле происходит при `volumes: dbdata: {}`
3. Как мне создать адекватную ссылку на машину хоста при помощи `docker-compose.yaml` так, что-бы я мог найти там данные БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

означает, что данные в контейнере по пути `/var/lib/postgresql/data` будут храниться в `volume dbdata`

Надо сделать:

```
- /var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

что бы данные из контейнера по пути `/var/lib/postgresql/data` фактически сохранялись в локальной файловой системе по такому же пути.

```
- путь_в_локальной_системе:путь_в_докере
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя в /var/lib/postgresql/data могут не сохраняться  данные из-за доступа,дай своему пользователю linux права sudo

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]